# How to access data of dynamic array of `int` when passed as function parameter?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, debugging

here in my code I'm trying to increment the value of a specific array index. The thing is when I increment it with `++` the value of it increments by 4 for some reason instead of 1. I believe the way I access the value of that index is wrong.

```
void updateData(char** usernames, int** userWins, int** userDraws, int** userDefeats,
    int totalUsers,char username1[],char username2[],int whoIsWinner,char againstPC){
  int i;
  printf("Username: %s.\tWins: %d.\tDraws: %d.\tDefeats: %d.\n",
      usernames[0],userWins[0],userDraws[0],userDefeats[0]);
  userWins[0]++;
  userDraws[0]++;
  userDefeats[0]++;
  printf("Username: %s.\tWins: %d.\tDraws: %d.\tDefeats: %d.\n",
      usernames[0],userWins[0],userDraws[0],userDefeats[0]);
}
```

[image: output]

userWins,userDraws,userDefeats are dynamic int arrays. I'm using ** because I want them passed by reference. Please ignore 5 last parameters of the function.

**EDIT:** added declaration and function call

```
int* userWins;
int* userDraws;
int* userDefeats;
userWins=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*totalUsers);
userDraws=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*totalUsers);
userDefeats=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*totalUsers);
updateData(usernames,userWins,userDraws,userDefeats,totalUsers,tempUsername1,
        tempUsername2,tempWinner,againstPC);
```

Comment: Note that `usernames` will be a pointer to a character array. Also, have you tried `*userWins[i]`?

Comment: yes, still the same results

Comment: Edit the question to show a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, for this question, it should show the original definitions of the objects passed to the function and should show the function call. Quite likely you are passing pointers to arrays (automatically converted from arrays of arrays), in which case the parameter declarations ought to follow the model `char usernames[][dimension]` or `char (*usernames)[dimension]`. But nobody can tell without the missing information.

Comment: @bruceg recall in operator precedence, `[]` binds tighter than `*`, so it likely requires `(*userWins)[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function takes in a double pointer, which means that in order to get the value you would have to dereference it twice. However, `userWins[0]` dereferences `userWins` once, and you get a pointer back. Then the `++` operator increments the value by the size of the pointer, which on your system is 4. If `userWins` is an array, simply pass it in as `int* userWins`.